# How to install tensorflow without internet connection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to install tensorflow in my PC (Windows 10) which doesnot have internet connection but I have downloaded the tensorflow package - tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl from the below link

https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files

I tried installing the .whl file in my windows 10 machine in conda prompt in Adminstrator mode, I get the below error message,

(base) C:\Windows\system32>pip install "C:\Python_Packages\tensorflow-1.14.0-cp3
7-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"

Processing c:\python_packages\tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Collecting tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0 (from tensorflow==1.14.0)

Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/tensorboard/

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1
.14.0 (from tensorflow==1.14.0) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0 (from tensorflow==1.14.0)

How to proceed with this offline tensorflow installation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try install TensorFlow without dependencies:

```
pip install --no-deps "C:\Python_Packages\tensorflow-1.14.0-cp3 7-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"
```

Comment: Now I am able install the tensorflow package. But while importing in jupyter notebook as "import tensorflow as tf" it throws me the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'". Is there a way to troubleshoot it ?

Comment: I would download wheels for missing packages and install them locally. You can find them at pypi.org, e.g [https://pypi.org/project/google/](https://pypi.org/project/google/) (Navigation/Download files)